# IE8 object does not support this property or method

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

I'm trying to make an IE fallback for Dave Dessandro's card flip script https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html and so far I have it working for every IE version except for 8. It's throwing the code error:

```
IE8 object does not support this property or method
```

Where the error seems to appear is in this line of code:

```
document.getElementById("info").addEventListener( "click", function(){
```

The complete function is here:

```
// Assign click action to flip card question
document.getElementById("info").addEventListener( "click", function(){
    card.toggleClassName("flipped");
    }, false);
};
```

I cannot see what the issue is? Is there anything that I am missing? For the complete code, please see https://github.com/SLQ-web/Fauna/blob/Koala/js/card-flip.js

Is this just something that IE8 refuses to do? It's a toggle that flips a card in 3D for browsers that support preserve3d and csstransform. For other older browsers, it just shows and hides the image. Have used Modernizr to set targeted classes.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not support `addEventListener`. You can use event handlers instead:

```js
document.getElementById("info").onclick = function() {
  card.toggleClassName("flipped");
};
```

Or, if you really need event listeners, IE8 has a non-standard `attachEvent`:

```js
document.getElementById("info").attachEvent('onclick', function() {
  card.toggleClassName("flipped");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick piece of advice. I will implement it now and check.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to solve that issue but I don't know how to rewrite this code: 'window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);'. I tried doing it with jQuery but it does not work.

Comment: IE8 does not support `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: Ok yeah I solved the issue by not using the init var method to start the function.